# Describing the Tychonoff topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

my question is:

> Describe the Tychonoff topology on $Y^X$ in a manner similar to the description
>   in below proposition of the compact-open topology.
>
> **Proposition:** If $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff and $Y$ is metric then the
>   compact-open topology on $Y^X$ is the topology of uniform convergence on
>   compact sets. That is, a net $f_a$ in $Y^X$ converges to $f\in Y^X$ in the compact-open topology if $f_a\upharpoonright K$ converges uniformly to $f\upharpoonright K$ for each compact set $K\subseteq X$.

It s a homework and its answer is very important for my friends and me.please help us.thanks a lot.

Comment: This is unreadable. Don't copy and paste from (e.g.) a PDF file.

Comment: Please see whether I correctly interpreted the unreadable parts.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Replace ‘for each compact set $K\subseteq X$’ with ‘for each point $x\in X$’.